# Unable to import and export classes and js file

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I’m am new to React and need to understand a concept. 
In my text editor there is a source file. Within the source folder I have created component folder as recommended by other sites. This comp folder holds my modules in jsx.
My question is, How do i import my `app.js` file to component folder modules. `App.js` is set as export default.
I believe i should use: `import App from 'app';` and for other modules `import ... from './src/comp/file.jsx'`.
is any of this correct.

Comment: are you using `create-react-app` ?

Comment: depends where your files are located for the paths, but yes. Your components should export your class via `export default Classname`, and then you can import them from any other file via `import Classname from '/directory/Classname' `

Comment: yes using create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

Your app.js doesn't export app.js per se, it exports whatever you export, probably a `class` or a `function` called App.

You probably don't want to import that (except maybe the root index.js did), but you might import another import another component into App, with something like:

    `import Header from './components/Header'`

That's assuming that you have a file called *index.js* in the subfolder *components/Header* and that file is exporting the Header class/function.

Comment: Thanks.  This helps.  My modules are in jsx. Which sources recommend.   Will jsx modules be a problem.  Or should I use them.   When importing a jsx to a different jsx.  Should I use the current module name then import it from previous model jsx

Comment: Sources say. They’re two different ways to do it.  Can’t figure out which one...?

Comment: This is a little outside my expertise, but I think it depends on your your enviroment is setup. I've had webpack setup to accept jsx files, but my current build (with create-react-app) just accepts the js files (with jsx in them, but with a js extension) without a problem.